# Embedding number fields in fields with class number prime to $p$

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, number-fields

Let $p$ be a fixed prime.

**Question:**

1. For any number field $K$, is there always a finite extension $L$ of $K$ of $p$-power order such that the class number of $L$ is prime to $p$?
2. Moreover, for any number field $K$ and any finite set $S$ of primes of $K$, is there always a finite extension $L$ of $K$ of $p$-power order such that $ L/K $ is unramified at any prime outside $ S $ the class number of $L$ is prime to $p$?

Comment: The answer to the question is No. One can show that a number field $K$ can be imbeded into another number field with class number prime to $p$ iff the degree of the maximal unramified $p$-extension (or $p$-class field tower) of $K$ is finite. But there are infinitely many examples of number fields with infinite $p$-class field tower. See Proposition 2 and Corollary 7 on p.231-234 of Algebraic Number Theory by Cassels and Frohlich.